# De onde surgiu a expressão "nasceu com o cu virado pra lua"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Às vezes quando uma pessoa tem muita sorte, mas muita sorte, algumas pessoas ainda dizem que ela "nasceu com o cu virado para lua". Um exemplo:

> Joãozinho tem um emprego bom, namora uma menina linda e já ganhou 18
>   vezes no bingo. Acho que ele nasceu com o cu virado pra lua!

Eu até encontrei [algumas variações](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascer_com_a_bunda_virada_para_a_Lua) como:

- Nascer com o cu virado para a Lua
- Nascer com o rabo virado para a Lua
- Nascer de rabo virado para a Lua
- Nascer de bunda virada para a Lua
- Nascer com a bunda virada para a lua
- Nascer com a bunda virada pra lua

Desde quando nascer com o "cu virado para a lua" pode ser considerado sorte? De onde surgiu essa expressão?

Comment: Tem a ver com o parto. Dizem que nasce com o cu para a lua quando se nasce com as pernas, e não com a cabeça. Na era sem cesariana, precisava ter sorte para sobreviver ao parto.

Comment: Penso que antigamente (até a poucos anos) era **«rabo virado pra lua»** ... **«cu»** deve ter surgido nos últimos anos... ainda mais se for BR... sem querer desmerece-nos. (ps: posso estar enganado pois pode ser variação regional)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e então «rabo virado pra lua» porquê? ehe

Comment: @acklay sim, eu entendo a motivação da pergunta, mas realmente portuguës não é meu forte :) ... só mencionei isto pq me recordava que quando criança era comum ouvir de uma maneira, mas com o passar dos anos isso mudou, estou curioso com a etimologia da relação da sorte com a lua, se isto é algo nacional, ou se estende para outros países (principalmente portugal). O comentário acima é mais para talvez fazer quem for responder pensar um pouco, no pt.se tem muitas respostas mais teóricas do que baseada em dados e fontes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi. Também escutei muito na minha infância, porque morava lá no "interiorzão" de minas e costumam muito falar isso por lá.

Comment: Procurei sobre essa pergunta pois fiquei com a pulga atras da orelha quando visitava a Sicilia. Ha uma placa com uma inscriçao em Siciliano que diz: "cu parra a la luna arricivi fortuna" - significa "quem fala com a lua, recebe sorte". Fiquei me questionando se nossa expressao nao seria uma corruptela desse proverbio Siciliano. :)

Comment: A única coisa de concreto que encontrei sobre isto é que a expressão aparece no Google Books a partir de 1961, com bastante frequência e muitas variantes.

Comment: Eu conheço uma forma menos chula **"Com a quina virada para a lua"** ou simplesmente **"de quina pra lua"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisei na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx), que tem o texto integral de centenas de periódicos brasileiros dos últimos dois séculos, e variadas expressões desse tipo aparecem a partir de 1949. Não encontrei nenhuma anterior, mas naturalmente já deviam existir na língua falada. Mostro abaixo as que encontrei entre 1949 e 1959, indicando os anos em que ocorrem. Clica no ano para ir à folha do jornal (a expressão está marcada a verde):

**Nascer ou andar virado para a lua** — resultados da busca na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx)

> Nasceu (sem indicar parte do corpo) virado para a lua  . . .  [1949](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_02&pesq=%22virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20194)  [52](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=112518_01&pesq=%22virado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [53](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22virados%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [54](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=112518_02&pesq=%22virado%20para%20lu%22a&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=004120&pesq=%22virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22virado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [57](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=386030&pesq=%22virado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Anda com o fígado  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093092_04&pesq=%22virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22figado%20virado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)   [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22f%C3%ADgado%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Anda com o nariz  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [1954](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093092_04&pesq=%22nariz%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Anda com o joelho  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    [1955](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22joelho%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22Bequinho%20com%20joelho%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Viu a luz do sol com o rosto  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . [1955](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22voltado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Nasceu com o joelho  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  [1956](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22nasceu%20com%20joelho%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22virado%20pra%20lua%20n%C3%A3o%22&pasta=ano%20195)   [57](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22canhoto%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Nasceu com o fígado  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .          [1956](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=154083_01&pesq=%22virado%20para%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)  [56](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22ceu%20com%20figado%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Nasceu de intestino  virado para a lua  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [1956](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22intestino%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Veio de Pernambuco com o fígado  virado para a lua    . . . . [1956](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=221961_03&pesq=%22buco%20com%20figado%20virado%20pra%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)
> Nasceu com a bundinha  virado para a lua . . . . . . . . . . . . . [1959](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=003581&pesq=%22virada%20para%20a%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20195)

Estes são os únicos dados concretos que eu consegui encontrar sobre a questão, e agora podemos ver o que é que eles nos dizem acerca da origem da expressão.

### Conjeturas sobre a origem da expressão

Encontram-se na net duas explicações, descritas em pormenor nas outras respostas. Uma diz que a expressão nasce de uma descrição do parto dos indiozinhos na famosa carta de Pero Vaz de Caminha aquando da chegada dos portugueses ao Brasil. Esta é fácil: a [carta está aqui](http://www.culturabrasil.org/zip/carta.pdf), é mesmo muito interessante, mas não fala de partos nem de luas.

Segundo a outra explicação, o nascimento de rabo é complicado, e o bebé que sobrevivesse a um parto desses era considerado sortudo. Esta tese parece-me muito duvidosa pelas seguintes razões:

1. Nenhum site em que encontrei esta tese explica como que sabe que foi assim que a expressão surgiu.
2. As 21 ocorrências mais antigas que encontrei destas expressões (ver acima) não fazem qualquer referência ao traseiro, e um terço delas não faz referência a nascimento. Os jornais poderiam sentir alguma relutância em publicar a palavra *cu* ou *rabo*, mas isso não explica não usarem uma palavra mais aceitável, como *bundinha* ou *traseiro*.
3. Não se entende o papel da lua nesta explicação. Presumivelmente, quem sobrevivesse a um nascimento de rabo seria sortudo independentemente de estar ou não virado para a lua. Poderia muito bem a lua estar abaixo da linha do horizonte, ou a parturiente virada para outro lado. Mas a lua, e não o traseiro ou o nascimento, é que é a constante nestas expressões (procurei expressões do tipo *nascer de rabo*, sem referência à lua, e não encontrei nada relacionado com sorte).
4. Se sobreviver a circunstâncias difíceis é indicador de sorte, porque é que não se diz dos sortudos, que eles nasceram numa casa a arder, ou durante a seca, ou durante a cheia ou guerra, ou que já foram atingidos por um raio?

Por tudo isto me parece que esta explicação não passa de um conjetura apresentada como verdade confirmada.

### A minha conjetura

O que se segue é também uma conjetura, mas tem menos problemas que as conjeturas acima. Parece-me possível que a expressão tenha nascido duma ideia qualquer, levada a sério ou não, acerca da influência da lua, e que *cu* ou *rabo* tenha sido acrescentado só para dar mais impacto. Pelo menos em Portugal há exemplos deste uso de *cu*, só para aumentar o impacto: *mexe-me esse cu* significa ’despacha-te, anda mais depressa’; *encher o cu a gulosos*, ’pagar a alguém, contribuir para enriquecer alguém (que não merece)’;  *não contes ao Manel, que ele vai logo meter tudo no cu de fulano*, ’o Manel vai contar tudo a fulano’ (eu só me lembro de ouvir esta a uma pessoa, mas vem no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa).

Dito isto, nascer ou andar com o fígado ou intestino virado para lua, como se encontra nalguns do exemplos dos anos 50, é uma ideia estranha. Talvez fosse código para *cu*. É possível que já se dissesse *cu virado para a lua*, mas que os jornais não quisessem publicar *cu*. Se fosse a posição da pessoa que interessasse, poderiam usar *bundinha* ou equivalente polido. Mas se o que interessasse fosse o impacto e brejeirice da palavra *cu*, o jornalista poderia preferir usar algo disparatado, como *fígado*, de modo a levar o leitor a entender *cu virado para a lua*.

Se isto faz sentido—se *fígado* era código para a palavra *cu*—*orangotangos* e *orangovalsas* seria código para quê?

> Só não fraturaram as canelas do crioulo porque o crioulo, Pelé, nasceu com todos os **orangotangos e os arangovalsas, todinhos, virados para a lua**. E cheia. E bochechuda.
> [José Amádio, *O Cruzeiro*, 17 de julho de 1974, p. 3.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=003581&pesq=%22virados%20para%20a%20lua%22&pasta=ano%20197)

Será que também dá sorte nascer com os tintins virados para a lua?

Answer (score 5):

Nascer com "cu virado para a lua" é porque  alguns bebês nascem ao contrário e  com a cabeça por último, onde a mortalidade dos mesmos na época era altíssima caso nascesse assim, e como nasciam de costas eles nasciam "com o cu virado para a lua". Portanto todo bebê que nasceu de costas e sobreviveu é alguém de muita sorte.

Não tem uma data especificada, apenas o motivo da origem que em determinado momento alguém falou assim, em alguma década do século passado, onde a medicina não era tão avançada, porém nem tão atrasada para que se tenha resultados melhores quanto a mortalidade do bebê no nascimento. Hoje é mais irrelevante, pois existem muitos métodos eficientes, como a própria cesariana.

Comment: É uma explicação até que bastante plausível. Há uma fonte que a ateste, ou se trata de uma etimologia popular?

Comment: Verdade @Seninha... eu particularmente achei bem interessante a explicação, no entanto é difícil dar uma certa credibilidade sem uma referência sequer.

Comment: @Seninha além disso quem é que garante que nasceu no Brasil. Essa expressão também é utilizada em Portugal.

Comment: @Seninha não encontrei nenhuma fonte realmente confiável, é apenas conhecimento passado anteriormente... é dificil encontrar a real fonte de expressões que não surgiram de forma factual ou de algum evento histórico, isso provavelmente foi alguém que simplesmente um dia disse " esse nasceu virado pra lua"

Comment: @JorgeB. removi porque concordo por não haver uma referencia realmente confiável, essa explicação é apenas , fulano falou pra fulano que falou pra tal e foi repassado. É apenas um conhecimento "perdido" que foi repassado, sem nenhuma base confiável.

Comment: @DanielGentil mas se calhar haverá alguma fonte que possa confirmar isso. Andei a pesquisar um bocado e ainda não encontrei nada. De qualquer forma a sua resposta é bem interessante.

Answer (score 2):

Explicação dada no "O olhar de Castro Alves - Ensaios críticos de literatura baiana" - [Volume 3](https://academiadeletrasdabahia.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/volume-3-1.pdf):

> Segundo Nélson Melo Cunha (2009), em  seu Dicionário de expressões coloquiais brasileiras, a expressão “nascer de bunda para a lua” e suas variantes, “Nascer de cu virado para a lua” significa ter sorte em tudo. Supostamente, a origem dessa expressão remonta a carta de Pero Vaz de Caminha ao rei de Portugal, explicando os hábitos das índias brasileiras, que realizavam o parto de cócoras e, portanto, o indiozinho caía “com o cu virado para a lua”. Desde esta época, se dizia que dava sorte nascer de bunda para a lua.

Infelizmente a fonte citada não é acadêmica e, como o Jacinto aponta em sua [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6106/2764), a referência à carta de Pero Vaz de Caminha é incorreta.

A explicação dada na [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4776/2764) do Daniel também é encontrada numa postagem de um [blog](http://meusditos.blogspot.com/2007/07/de-bunda-pr-lua.html) (ativo em 2007) citando como fonte "Li dia desses no jornal":

> As crianças nascem de cabeça, isto é, a cabeça é a primeira a sair, como se a se certificar que está em segurança. Quando o parto é feito com a bunda em primeiro lugar é necessária muita perícia médica e muita sorte para a criança nascer viva e feliz. Daí presumir-se que os nascidos nesta posição já nascem com sorte.

Comment: Tens aqui a [carta de Pero Vaz de Caminha](http://www.culturabrasil.org/zip/carta.pdf). Nem uma palavra acerca do modo de nascimento dos indiozinhos. Extraordinário como há gente que põe estas coisas em livros! Mas a carta é muito interessante; vale a pena ler.

Comment: @Jacinto Excelente, eu deveria ter tentado verificar também. Já editei a resposta.