# O que significa a palavra "cudada" usada por Luís de Camões?

Tags: significado, etimologia, interpretação

O que Luís de Camões quis dizer com a palavra *cudada*? Seria isso alguma forma pejorativa de expressar-se? Ou não sendo, poderia também ser usada de forma pejorativa?

Comment: De acordo com o dicionário Aulete, “cudar” é uma palavra antiga, equivalente a “cuidar”, então, creio que “cudada” seja equivalente a “cuidada”; porém, se for possível, podes escrever o verso contendo essa palavra no texto? Ajudaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Cudar*** e derivados — ***cudada, cudado***, etc. — são variantes antigas de *cuidar* e derivados. Foi usado por Camões e outros escritores também. Entre os dicionários atuais, encontrei apenas [*cudar* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cudar), que descreve o termo como antigo ou popular. Mas o dicionário de [Domingo Vieira, 1873](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lJhaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA653&dq=%22CUDAR%20Vid%20cuidar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi847uhscHtAhU97uAKHTlFAN8Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22CUDAR%20Vid%20cuidar%22&f=false), ainda traz *cudado*, *cudar* e também *cudo* (mesmo que *cuido*, ’ato de cuidar’):

[image: Cudado]

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), nos verbetes *cuidado* e *cuidar*, indica as variantes antigas *cudado* e *cudar*.

Agora, atenção que nos tempos de Camões, *cuidar*, ou *cudar*, significava principalmente ’pensar, refletir, dar atenção a’ (*cuidar* vem do latim *cogitare*). Por exemplo, nestes [versos de Camões](https://books.google.pt/books?id=goBJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA151-IA1&lpg=PA151-IA1&dq=%22vendome%20ir%20maltratado%22&source=bl&ots=QrOD_a2l6B&sig=ACfU3U2LkhN7O07E7Jbd_LnbIfZO6wwWbw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOrc2dusHtAhVSDmMBHTh7CtYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vendome%20ir%20maltratado%22&f=false), *cudado* parece significar ’pensamento’ ou talvez ’preocupação’ (*cuidado*, em Portugal, ainda hoje significa ’preocupação’, especialmente na expressão *estar em cuidados*):

> E vendome ir maltratado,
> eu & meu **cudado** sòs,
> pouco nisso d’atentado,
> por não me ausentar de voz.
> Sem vos, & com meu **cudado**.
> [Rhymas de Luis de Camões, divididas em cinco partes, Lisboa 1595](https://books.google.pt/books?id=goBJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA151-IA1&lpg=PA151-IA1&dq=%22vendome%20ir%20maltratado%22&source=bl&ots=QrOD_a2l6B&sig=ACfU3U2LkhN7O07E7Jbd_LnbIfZO6wwWbw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOrc2dusHtAhVSDmMBHTh7CtYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vendome%20ir%20maltratado%22&f=false)

Já neste “por não cudada via” de [Camões (op. cit.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=goBJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22n%C3%A3o%20cudada%22&source=bl&ots=QrOD_a3k_A&sig=ACfU3U0Itrj8-LAdy9oRiECfTe0oK53utg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKzbWkvcHtAhXp6eAKHfJaB-gQ6AEwBHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22n%C3%A3o%20cudada%22&f=false), *não cudada* significará talvez ’irrefletida, precipitada’ ou ’imprevista’; o mesmo neste “brevidade não cudada” de [Bernardo de Brito (*Monarchia Lusytana*, 1609)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=jV5JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA330-IA1&dq=%22cudada%20desde%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQqoWCvsHtAhUMkhQKHZmVDpoQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22cudada%20desde%22&f=false). Já neste [*Tractado das significaçoens das plantas, flores, e fructos* de Isidoro Barreira, 1612](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PWRP-4GYRaUC&pg=PA11&dq=cudado&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLlJCR0cDtAhUJZMAKHbOVCVsQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=cudado&f=false) tudo se compreende sem dificuldade:

> Diz Seneca philosopho, que muitas arvores por **descudo** de quem tem **cudado** dellas, nacem tortas & crecem com defeitos: o que não fora se no principio lhe acodirão [’não seria se no princípio lhe acudissem’]. Os filhos saõ plantas que Deos comete ao pays pera que tenhão **cudado** dellas, & creção sem defeito & desordem da vida

### Sobre a origem

Segundo o dicionário Houaiss surgiu primeiro *cuidado*, e só depois *cudado*, o que faz sentido, já que a palavra vem do latim *cogitātum*. Na evolução do latim para o português, além de se perder o *m* final (aconteceu em todas as palavras) e do *t* intervocálico passar a *d* em imensas palavras, houve alguma tendência para se perder o *g* intervocálico, logo *cogi*- passaria a *coi*- (do mesmo modo do latim *rugitum* veio-nos *rugido* e também *ruído*). Cito o Houaiss (desenvolvendo algumas abreviações; ortografia anterior ao AO90):

> **cuidado** [...] ETIM latim *cogitātus,a,um* ’meditado, pensado, reflectido’, particípio passado de *cogitāre* ’agitar no espírito, remoer no pensamento, pensar, meditar, projectar, preparar’; ver *cuid*-; formas históricas s[éculo ]XIII *cuidado*, sXIII *coydado*, sXIX *cujdado*, sXV *cudado*

No século XVI encontram-se *cuidado* e *cudado*, por vezes na mesma obra, como nestas [Rhythmas de Luis de Camoes](https://books.google.pt/books?id=e4klAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA146-IA1&dq=%22Tanto%20mayores%20tormentos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihs-38mcvtAhVCrxoKHS6hAEoQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Tanto%20mayores%20tormentos%22&f=false) de 1595 (aparece *cuidados* acima do trecho destacado, e *cudados* várias vezes abaixo). Parece portanto que *cudado*, etc. foram formas que se formaram de *cuidado* por simplificação, coexistiram com as originais durante algum tempo e depois caíram em desuso.

Comment: Jacinto, interessante esse significado antigo para “cu(i)dar”. Isso também deixa claro aquela famosa frase “cogito ergo sum”, que é “penso, logo, existo”, já que como eu sou nerd de etimologia, sei que “cu(i)dar” vem do latim “cogitare” (cogitare > *coiidar > coidar > cu(i)dar); também interessante para a palavra “cogitar”, mas esta é nova: o Houssaiss diz 1780, uma época de latinismos. Na minha pequena experiência, o Aulete tem mais palavras antigas do que outros dicionários famosos, então, é normal. Parabéns e obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @Schilive, pois, eu foi ao contrário: eu nunca tinha pensado na origem de *cuidar*; já sabia era o significado de *cogitar*, e por isso quando vi que *cuidar* vinha de *cogitare*, incluí essa observação por, para mim, explicar imediatamente o significado antigo de *cuidar*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Acho sempre interessante comparar as palavras usadas antigamente com as usadas atualmente. Essa que no passado tinha um significado, hoje parece ser outra com um significado diferente. Mas isso significa que não existe um significado diferente hoje? Porquê parece muito mais uma palavra pejorativa do que a usada em algumas regiões "cuada", que apesar de parecer ruim, é usada no sentido de menina ou mulher que tem as nádegas grandes, avantajadas.

Comment: Jacinto, é uma sugestão boba, mas não seria mais correto dizer “‘cudar’ e desinências”, já que “derivados” se usa geralmente para palavras vindas de (ex.: “desuso” é derivado de “uso”)? Também encontrei glossa.gal/glosario/termo/995, que ajude a entender o “não cudado”.

Comment: @Schilive, *desinência* é o sufixo: por exemplo, em *cudei* a desinência é *-ei*. Eu usei *derivado* num sentido lato, incluindo aí palavras como *descudo*, o substantivo *cudado* e outras que possam existir.

Comment: @renanlinux, nos muitos exemplos que encontrei, *cudada, cudado*, etc. não têm sentido pejorativo. Por exemplo, "não cudada via" (do Camões) parece-me negativo, mas é por causa do *não*; *cudada via* já seria positivo. Agora, talvez nos exemplos que viste seja pejorativo. Se os incluíres na pergunta, já me poderei pronunciar. *Cudada*, nos exemplos que vi, não tem dada que ver com *cuada* (que vem de *cu*); caso não tenha ficado claro, *cudada* é o mesmo que *cuidada*  (vêm em vários dicionários antigos). Como nem deste um voto à minha resposta, imagino que não tenhas ficado satisfeito...

Comment: Não sabia que eu já podia dar votos positivos. Fazia tanto tempo que não usava a comunidade, que não lembrava já ter recebido o privilégio. Eu achei vários significados parecidos num site, não lembro qual. Por isso veio a dúvida, porque parecia que essa palavra também encaixava-se no mesmo significado. Achei muito estranho que Camões dissesse isso em seu livro de maior sucesso.

Comment: @renan, falas d'Os Lusíadas? Estive a ver as primeiras edições, 1572; só encontrei *cuidada* (ou *cuydada*). Realmente, porque não editas a pergunta e incluis a passagem com o *cudada*? Ajudaria muito. Encontrei [nesta rimas de Camões](https://books.google.pt/books?id=e4klAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA146-IA1&dq=%22Tanto+mayores+tormentos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihs-38mcvtAhVCrxoKHS6hAEoQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Tanto%20mayores%20tormentos%22&f=false) um exemplo curioso: no título vem *cuidados*, mas nos versos é sempre *cudados*. Até podes dar votos negativos; e aceitar a resposta, se te parecer bem.

Comment: @Schilive, li a cara te Pero Vaz de Caminha recentemente, a propósito [desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4688/de-onde-surgiu-a-express%c3%a3o-nasceu-com-o-cu-virado-pra-lua), e achei curioso o comentário dele (e ele demonstrar em carta ao rei tão profundo conhecimento das "vergonhas" das portuguesas), mas não vi nada de pejorativo nem palavras com significados incertos: *vergonha* era eufemismo para ’órgãos genitais’, e ele disse que as portuguesas se envergonhariam por as "vergonhas" delas não serem tão bem feitinhas como as das índias.

Comment: Não me lembrava disso diretamente do livro. Agora não vou conseguir encontrar o site no qual li isso. Havia pouca coisa escrita, dizia a palavra cudada, sem que houvesse o suficiente para eu entender isso numa frase, e, procurando, acabei encontrando um site com várias palavras parecidas, mas sem explicar exatamente a cudada.

Comment: @renanlinux, acrescentei uma imagem dum dicionário antigo e uma nota sobre a evolução de *cuidado* e *cudado*. Talvez estejas interessado.

Comment: @renanlinux, como não aceitaste a resposta, mas também não fizeste nenhuma crítica, há alguma coisa que tu achas que está errada ou que precisa de ser mais bem esclarecida? Alguma coisa que eu possa melhorar para a resposta merecer a tua aceitação?

Comment: Desculpe, quando você respondeu essa pergunta, eu não sabia que tinha um sinal para marcar como resposta. Quando toco para dar um voto positivo, aparece dizendo que posso adicionar como resposta, mas ainda não tinha encontrado como.

Comment: @renanlinux, tudo bem. E não és obrigado a aceitar respostas; eu só queria saber se estavas ou não completamente satisfeito com a resposta; se estás, tanto melhor.